# Android Firebase ignores orderByValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a leader board that retrieves the top 10 players. The data gets displayed properly on the first call but whenever onPause/onStop and then onResume/onStart gets called, the data is no longer in its sorted order and it appears as if the `orderByValue()` method gets ignored. I attach the listeners on the `onStart()` method and removing it on the `onStop()` method. This is driving me crazy.

```
 //get the active week id to use for reference
String week_id = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.getPreferenceFile(),
  Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.getActiveWeek(),null);
//initialize the database references
if(leader_board_child_event_listener == null) {
  leader_board_reference = MainActivity.firebaseDatabase.getRef().child(Constants.getLeaderBoardChild());
  user_reference = MainActivity.firebaseDatabase.getRef().child(Constants.getUsersChild());
  Log.d(TAG, "sorting the query first");
  leader_board_query = leader_board_reference.child(week_id).orderByValue().limitToLast(10);

  leader_board_child_event_listener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
      Log.d(TAG, "child added == " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
      //get the user details every time child added is called
      user_reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
          hideProgressBar();
          //add the user details to a list
          user_list.add(new User(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot2.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).
            child(Constants.getUserNameChild()).getValue(String.class), dataSnapshot2.
            child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(Constants.getProfilePicUriChild()).getValue(String.class),
            dataSnapshot.getValue(double.class)));
          //update the recyclerview adapter with each addition
          board_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Log.d(TAG, "user details: " + user_list.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  };
}
//add the listener to leader board database reference
leader_board_query.addChildEventListener(leader_board_child_event_listener);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which activity life-cycle methods are you adding (and removing?) `leader_board_child_event_listener`?

Comment: @qbix I attach the listeners on the onStart() method and removing it on the onStop() method.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `onChildAdded()` is called for each child when the listener is added.  If that's right, you would need to clear `user_list` before adding the listener each time.  Is that done?